# The linkage of two highcharts-ng in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, highcharts

I hope that when I zoom $scope.chart1, $scope.chart.options.chart.type will be changed like $scope.removeRandomSeries. But no matter what I do (more details in $scope.chart1.options.chart.events.selection), it is useless.

But when clicking "Remove Random Series" button, it works. But I do not want to press button each time, I hope it can update automatically.

You can see at http://jsfiddle.net/abc4329803/ezc38gxx/4/

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="myctrl">
        <h3><a href="https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng">Using version 0.01 of Highcharts-ng</a></h3>
        <h5><a href="https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng">Newer version available...</a></h5>
        <input ng-model="chart.title.text">
        <button ng-click="addSeries()">Add Series</button>
        <button ng-click="addPoints()">Add Points to Random Series</button>
        <button ng-click="removeRandomSeries()">Remove Random Series</button>
        <button ng-click="swapChartType()">Line/Bar</button>
        <highchart id="chart" series="chart.series" title="chart.title" options="chart.options"></highchart>
        <highchart id="chart1" series="chart1.series" title="chart1.title" options="chart1.options"></highchart>
    </div>
</div>
<h3><a href="https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng">See Highcharts-ng on github</a></h3>
//See: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);

myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.addPoints = function () {
        var seriesArray = $scope.chart.series
        var rndIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * seriesArray.length);
        seriesArray[rndIdx].data = seriesArray[rndIdx].data.concat([1, 10, 20])
    };

    $scope.addSeries = function () {
        var rnd = []
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            rnd.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1)
        }
        $scope.chart.series.push({
            data: rnd
        })
    }

    $scope.removeRandomSeries = function () {
        var seriesArray = $scope.chart.series
        var rndIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * seriesArray.length);
        seriesArray.splice(rndIdx, 1)
    }

    $scope.options = {
        type: 'line'
    }

    $scope.swapChartType = function () {
        if ($scope.chart.options.chart.type === 'line') {
            $scope.chart.options.chart.type = 'bar'
        } else {
            $scope.chart.options.chart.type = 'line'
        }
    }

    $scope.chart = {
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]
        }],
        title: {
            text: 'Hello1'
        }
    }
                $scope.chart1 = {
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                zoomType : 'xy',
                events : {
                    selection : function (event) {
                        console.log($scope.chart.options.chart.type);
                                if ($scope.chart.options.chart.type === 'line') {
            $scope.chart.options.chart.type = 'bar'
        } else {
            $scope.chart.options.chart.type = 'line'
        }
        //console.log($scope.chart.options.chart.type);

                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]
        }],
        title: {
            text: 'Hello1'
        }


    }
        $scope.chart1.options.chart.events.selection = function (event){
            console.log(event);
            console.log($scope.chart.options.chart.type);
            if ($scope.chart.options.chart.type === 'line') {
            $scope.chart.options.chart.type = 'bar'
        } else {
            $scope.chart.options.chart.type = 'line'
        }
        console.log($scope.chart.options.chart.type);
        }

});
```

Comment: Call digest manually - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest - see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ezc38gxx/5/

Comment: It is Ok! Thanks~